# Jquery ui Progressbar for every postback in asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

Can you help me on how to use Jquery UI Progress bar for every postback in asp.net? I really don't know how to start I'm new to Jquery UI. I have an UpdateProgress but it doesn't work on my jquery ui dialog so I wanted to try Jquery UI Progress bar. Any suggestion will be helpful! Thank you.

So far I have this code for the progressbar i don't know how to make it work like the UpdateProgress.

```
$(function() {
$( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
  value: false
});
```

ASP:

```
<div id="progressbar">
</div>
```

this is my existing code that does not work in my button inside of Jquery UI dialog.

```
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1">
    <ProgressTemplate>
        <div class="modal">
            <div class="center" align="center">
                Processing Data, Please wait..
                <img alt="" src="images/loader.gif" />
            </div>
        </div>

    </ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and include some of the code you have tried? If you narrow down your issue, you are likely to receive better, quicker help.

Comment: @MarioTacke    Ok I updated the question.